# Positioning the Items using Layouts in qml

Tags: layout, qml, positioning

I started learning about Layouts and i am trying to position the elements using Layouts (ColumnLayout & RowLayout) but unable to position the rectangle (green one with Width&Height 50) on to the right side of the screen, whatever i my do i can't bring it to the right side if i am using RowLayout inside a ColumnLayout.

Expected position of Green rectangle [image]

Any help here will be appreciated

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10

        RowLayout{

            //implicitWidth: parent.width
            //implicitHeight: parent.height
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            Rectangle{
                width: 50
                height: 50

                color: "orange"
            }

            Rectangle{
                width: 50
                height: 50

                color: "blue"
            }

            Rectangle{
                width: 50
                height: 50

                color: "green"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight
            }
        }
        RowLayout {
            Rectangle{
                width: 370
                height: 800

                color: "cyan"
            }

            Rectangle{
                width: 370
                height: 800

                color: "pink"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regard's,

Rohith.G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an empty Item as a placeholder:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
visible: true
width: 800
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")
ColumnLayout{
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 10

    RowLayout{

        //implicitWidth: parent.width
        //implicitHeight: parent.height
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        Rectangle{
            width: 50
            height: 50

            color: "orange"
        }

        Rectangle{
            width: 50
            height: 50

            color: "blue"
        }

        // placeholder item taking the remaining space
        Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Rectangle{
            width: 50
            height: 50

            color: "green"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight
        }
    }
    RowLayout {
        Rectangle{
            width: 370
            height: 800

            color: "cyan"
        }

        Rectangle{
            width: 370
            height: 800

            color: "pink"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows the same solution provided by @JürgenLutz however, I provided this answer because I wanted additional points.

If parent is a non-Layout component, e.g. Window, Item, Rectangle, Label, Text, ListView, Row, Column:

- Use anchors for positioning this component
- Use width, height for sizing

If a parent is a Layout component, e.g. RowLayout, ColumnLayout, GridLayout:

- Use Layout.alignment for positioning
- Use Layout.preferredWidth, Layout.preferredHeight, Layout.fillWidth or Layout.fillHeight for sizing

I make these points because all your Rectangles are parented in a RowLayout. Therefore, they should not use width and height. They should use Layout.preferredWidth and Layout.preferredHeight. This is because, the actual placement and sizing are taken care of by the RowLayout.

Also, when you Layouts there should be fewer occurrences of absolute numbers, so, the bottom two Rectangles can use Layout.fillWidth and Layout.fillHeight instead of specifying width and height:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Rectangle {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 50
                Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                color: "orange"
            }
            Rectangle {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 50
                Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                color: "blue"
            }
            Item { Layout.fillWidth: true }
            Rectangle {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 50
                Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                color: "green"
            }
        }
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "cyan"
            }
            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "pink"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAEVniczVK7DsIwDNz7FREfgGBg6doFJAZgYQ6pSSPSOHIdIVT133mjFmhBCAm85Xy27xyb3COxmPM8GLWJTOPZT9AxoS3u8ancYeAimkkNoozEIRK0IXfnxAU6hnQqQyr6a2NtLLwkcHxLFl4q43QshoMbtsDtQ5NjnMFTn6VJOYsFU4AGZQGKpdMW7kpr5Z5gDUSQXnqMBi+ZYzA646dUhRYpFj2kw1joNfLVf0hb2dApbMKQi7Jlu/9iQhOAa3NRfeN0apSrnk/Oq2vEu2PqxtVOtvr+kSRv3Kb7K6qo2gPrdR5D)